# Getting the text from a label inside a List View VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to retrieve the text from a Label within a List View control. The method I am using, below, will only retrieve the first piece of text I want. The text I am looking for is an ID, therefore I am always returning the first ID no matter what item I click on.

```
Private Sub guidelinesList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles guidelinesList.SelectedIndexChanged
    i = guidelinesList.SelectedIndex
End Sub

Private Sub guidelinesList_ItemDataCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles guidelinesList.ItemCommand

    Dim theIdLabel As Label = CType(guidelinesList.Items(i).FindControl("lblId"), Label)

    guidelinesId = CInt(theIdLabel.Text)

    If String.Equals(e.CommandName, "bEdit") Then
        Response.Redirect("../EditFile.aspx?FileId=" & guidelinesId & "&FileType=Guidelines" & "&AppType=Payroll")
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Small code change is all that was needed, see below.

```
Private Sub guidelinesList_ItemDataCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ListViewCommandEventArgs) Handles guidelinesList.ItemCommand

    If String.Equals(e.CommandName, "bEdit") Then
        Dim i As Integer = CInt(e.Item.DataItemIndex)

        Dim theIdLabel As Label = CType(guidelinesList.Items(i).FindControl("lblId"), Label)

        guidelinesId = CInt(theIdLabel.Text)
        Response.Redirect("../EditFile.aspx?FileId=" & guidelinesId & "&FileType=Guidelines" & "&AppType=Payroll")
    End If
End Sub
```